# Error when trying to run pairwise comparison in a loop in R

Tags: r, rstatix

This error throws when I try to run this code. The anova and anova results function without issuse. Why is the column in the pairwise_t_test not the same as the dv= column in the anova.

Error in `pull()`:
! Can't extract columns that don't exist.
✖ Column `column` doesn't exist.

```
library(rstatix)

nnames <- names(df)[unlist(lapply(df, is.numeric))]
res.aov <- list()
aov_tab <- list()
pc <- list()
pc1 <- list()

for (column in nnames) {
  res.aov[[column]] <- anova_test(data = df, dv = column, 
                                  wid = `Subject`, within = `Timepoint`, between = `Genotype`)
  aov_tab[[column]] <- get_anova_table(res.aov[[column]])
  
  pc[[column]]<- df %>% pairwise_t_test(column ~`Timepoint`, paired=TRUE, p.adjust.method = "holm")
  pc[[column]]<- pc[[column]] %>% add_xy_position(x="Timepoint")
  
  pc1[[column]]<- df %>% group_by(Timepoint) %>% pairwise_t_test(column ~ `Genotype`)
  pc1[[column]]<- pc1[[column]] %>% add_xy_position(x= "Timepoint")
  }
```

dataframe

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Subject = c("ASCVD002", "ASCVD002", "ASCVD002", 
"ASCVD003", "ASCVD003", "ASCVD003", "ASCVD004", "ASCVD004", "ASCVD004", 
"ASCVD005", "ASCVD005", "ASCVD005", "ASCVD006", "ASCVD006", "ASCVD006", 
"ASCVD008", "ASCVD008", "ASCVD008", "ASCVD009", "ASCVD009", "ASCVD009", 
"ASCVD010", "ASCVD010", "ASCVD010", "ASCVD011", "ASCVD011", "ASCVD011"
), Timepoint = c("0", "0.25", "0.5", "0", "0.25", "0.5", "0", 
"0.25", "0.5", "0", "0.25", "0.5", "0", "0.25", "0.5", "0", "0.25", 
"0.5", "0", "0.25", "0.5", "0", "0.25", "0.5", "0", "0.25", "0.5"
), Genotype = c("Heterozygote", "Heterozygote", "Heterozygote", 
"Heterozygote", "Heterozygote", "Heterozygote", "Heterozygote", 
"Heterozygote", "Heterozygote", "GG", "GG", "GG", "AA", "AA", 
"AA", "GG", "GG", "GG", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "GG", 
"GG", "GG"), `Tregs CD127lo CD25+` = c(2702, 2175, 2651, 1672.8, 
3762, 4264, 1975, 3208, 3285, 3457, 3383, 2619.9, 11872, 16101, 
13443, 3935, 1894, 2297, 7385, 8901, 9522, 7100, 8789, 9309, 
371, 379, 514), `Monocytes % of Live by Size` = c(1.38, 2.66, 
4.74, 5.83, 3.9, 5.06, 6.36, 3.45, 2.64, 6.33, 10.7, 9.41, 3.42, 
3.46, 2.73, 2.38, 3.12, 4.44, 5.31, 3.59, 4.91, 1.53, 6.54, 4.85, 
6.87, 3.66, 5.07), `NK cells` = c(90.62, 153.6, 159.8, 88, 118, 
159, 74, 82, 64, 30, 344, 73, 29, 198, 79, 145, 258, 307, 30, 
74.4, 0, 47.3, 32, 0, 52.6, 95.3, 51.7)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -27L))
```

I have ran it out of the loop and used the specific column without the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `pairwise_t_test` you provide a formula that contains "column". The object `column` is a length 1 vector containing the name (!) of the variable you are interested in but not the values of the variable itself. The formula needs to have the actual variable name in it, not an object referring to the variable.

You can avoid this by constructing the formula like this:

```
pairwise_t_test(as.formula(paste0("`",column,"`", "~ Timepoint")), ...)
```

And likewise in the second call to `pairwise_t_test`.

By the way, you have very unhandy variable names in `nnames`. With more simple variable names (no spaces or special characters) you do not need the `` "`" `` in the code.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I know the colnames are a bit clunky but I plan on putting these pairwise values onto plots of each column vs timepoint grouped by genotype. I'm still quite new to this a lot of this. Is there a good way to change the names for the statistic commands but keep them for the eventual plots I want to put them on? If that is unclear I can add the code for the ggplot I plan to place them on as I have that part working.

Comment: With ggplot, I agree that it makes sense to keep the names to be plotted in the dataframe itself. You may want to switch to simpler names and store the longer ones outside the dataframe, e.g. in a named vector, then rename the columns in the dataframe just for printing. But this only makes sense if the long names cause you trouble during data preparation.